# Which network layer is in charge of reassembling fragmented datagrams?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, network-protocols, sharppcap

Recently I dug a bit deeper into the matter of network protocols and the OSI model, when noticed, that incoming TCP datagrams (correct me if this is the wrong term) are splitted into several parts, when they exceed a certain size - in this case it's propably my router's MTU. I captured those datagrams using SharpPcap in order to extract some information i am looking for, if you are wondering where I got this information from.

Anyway I was wondering if the reassembly of fragmented packets shouldn't be task of the IP layer, since it definitely provides information to accomplish this (id, fragmentation flags, fragment offset). Furthermore I read, that the TCP layer is to be interpreted as a stream-based protocol. But this actually implies, that it's up to the TCP layer to care about filling the application's buffer the *right* way, so that the initial piece of information is reconstructed and may be flushed "*up*" all further layers.

Before I made this observation I actually thought, that the TCP layer should care about reassembling those datagrams, but none of the mentioned layers does...

This leads to the following question(s): 
**Why are the TCP datagrams I receive not reassembled** and **what layer SHOULD actually take care about this?**

Comment: The correct term is either 'IP packet' or 'TCP segment' depending on what exactly you're talking about. 'Datagram' is a UDP term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip layer handles fragmentation and reassembly, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation.

When you use a tool like SharpPcap that uses winpcap/airpcap/libpcap, you are receiving the raw datagrams from the device you are capturing on. For many adapters this is an ethernet datagram that then contains an ip frame etc.

This is in contrast to data received after processing by the networking stack, where the reassembly is performed.

So, its expected that you won't get reassembled datagrams from SharpPcap (or many other capture libraries) because the data is being captured at the adapter level, not inside of our as an output of the networking stack that is performing reassembly.

You can perform the reassembly after capture either yourself or using a library that provides this functionality. You could also add such a component to Packet.Net (the packet processing library that SharpPcap is using) to provide this reassembly.

Comment: The first statement in this answer is not correct. The receiving host (destination) handles the reassembly. As per your reference: `The fragments are reassembled by the receiving host.` And as per other references: `When an IP datagram is fragmented, it is not reassembled until it reaches its final destination.` (http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/udp_user.htm) Just wanted to clarify for others.